# Get Corona image size without loading it

Tags: width, coronasdk

I would like to know how to obtain image size using Corona without loading them and call obj.width.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if your image is PNG, Yeah!
http://developer.coronalabs.com/forum/2012/05/16/pnglib-extract-data-png-files-width-height-color-depth-etc

Even for jpeg images, I think someone suggested a way.